# Using Livewire, expand the search bar with the search icon and display the close symbol when clicked

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Using Livewire, I'm attempting to open the expanded search bar along with a search icon and a close icon upon click. We sincerely appreciate your assistance in advance.
To make it even clearer, I've included an image as well.
I want to change my code from being on hover to being on click.

here is an example:
https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/0*T-iTKJmWEryjQPqi.gif

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to make public property like

`public $expanded = false;` in you livewire component class. Then you need to make in css both states when it is expanded and closed.

Preferrably maybe if class exists so then in your component blade you can do something like:

```
<div class="{{ $expanded == true ? 'expand-class' : ''}}"><form><input></input></form></div>
```

That is it.

Comment: can someone explain why this is down-voted? This is literally how you do "animations" if needed in lw